# Using distance and transform from geomfromtext from postgis in spatialite

Tags: spatialite, android

I have the following query which I want to apply on my from postgis to spatialite imported database. The problem is that the result of the distance is always null, while the other selected coloumns are containing the expected values. So how can I use this query in spatial lite? It should calculate the distance from the given point to all in the databases stored points and sort them by the distance.

```
"select x1, y1, source, st_distance(st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(' || x1 || ' ' || y1 || ')',4326),32633),st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(15.442161 47.068170)',4326),32633)) from tablex order by st_distance asc limit 1;"
```

I tried it in spatialite with the following query:

```
"select x1, y1, source, distance(transform(geomfromtext('POINT(' || x1 || ' ' || y1 || ')',4326),32633),transform(geomfromtext('POINT(15.442161 47.068170)',4326),32633)) from tablex order by distance asc limit 1;"
```

If I do not use the transform function I get the right result, but the distance is in degrees and not in metres, as I would need it.

Comment: Do you get expected results from: SELECT transform(geomfromtext('POINT(' || x1 || ' ' || y1 || ')',4326),32633) from tablex; ??

Comment: Yes, in my postgis database it is working. x1 and y1 are the values taken from the database query.

Comment: What about in Spatialite?

Comment: The result in the column distance is NULL and not a result. If I do not apply transformation, then I get a result, but the it is in degree and not in metres, as I already wrote in my posting.

Comment: If you do ONLY the Transform() in Spatialite, without the Distance() function, do you get correct results?

Comment: If I do only transformation, I get a right transformation.

Comment: So your problem is the Distance() function. I have seen some weird results with Distance() on a Scientific Linux 6 machine. What OS are you on, and how did you install Spatialite? Can I suggest to report this problem in the Spatialite-users maillist (including the OS details, and a sample of the data, if possible)?

Comment: At the moment I use Windows 7 with spatialite gui to do the queries. Later this database will move to android and is used there as productive database. I'm not sure if I'm already eligible to post pictures. If I can do, then I will post some here later.

Comment: I was just trying to make screenshots for you. I figured out that transform and geomfromtextdo not work together. So the result with transform(geomfromtext(....)) is NULL.